# How to change Access-Control-Allow-Origin in AppMobi emulator

Tags: jquery, cordova, appmobi

I'm trying to access file from a server:

```
$.get('http://server.com/methods.php?m=loadSomething', function(data) {

    console.log(data);

});
```

But I get error:

```
Origin http://localhost:58888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Is there any way to change Access-Control settings so I can access the remote server and obtain data?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you have access to `server.com` as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a header option that has to be sent by the server.

Comment: I do have an access, can you be more specific how to set this option? Thanks.

Comment: Inside the `methods.php` just use the `header()` method like `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:58888')`

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me out. Add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `methods.php` just use the `header()` method like

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:58888')
```